# How to normalize TOTAL INTENSITY of two images? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, normalize

I have two images with same dimensions. I want to make the *total intensity* of these two images to be the same. For example, image A has total intensity of 100, I want the image B to also have the same total intensity of 100. I have tried to normalize each of *pixel intensities* in image A and B within the same range, say 0 to 1, but the *total intensity* of these two images are still not equal. Could someone please tell me how to do this? I would appreciate it if you could discuss it in Matlab environment. Thank you.

Comment: definition of "total intensity"?

Comment: Hi, @ChristophRackwitz, what I meant by "total intensity" is the summation of all the pixel values in one image. Say, original pixel values of image A has an array of [3 45 12] and image B is [66 23 9]. Each thus has total intensity of 60 and 98, respectively. I want to make these images A and B to have an equal total intensity when adding up each pixel value in each image. What should I do to the pixel values in order to have two images with equal total intensity?

Comment: the "correct" operation is scaling (multiplication/division). I don't think I should mention "gamma mapping" here because that's complicating the situation even more.

Answer (score 0):

Divide both images by the sum of you pixels. Sum of pixels of both images will be 1. Example for 10x10 randomly generated images:

```
A=rand(10,10);
B=rand(10,10);

A_rescaled=A./sum(A,'all');
B_rescaled=B./sum(B,'all');
```